# Android Linkify text - Spannable Text in Single Text View - As like Twitter tweet

Tags: android, textview, linkify, spannablestring

I have a textView and text like

"This is the Simple Text with **KeyWord** and the **Link** to browse"

in the above text i want to make..

**clicking on the Link goes to open that URL**
AND
**clicking on that KeyWord open a new Activity in my application**

also,
**There is an click event for the Whole TextView even.**

Please help me finding a solution.
Thank You,
MKJParekh

Comment: Well, I guess this is what you are looking for [Android Custom Hyperlinked TextView](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://www.orangeapple.org/)

Comment: I think you should check : http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/text/Link.html http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/wikinotes-linkify.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used the same thing which I answered here in [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137008/how-to-make-listitem-textview-to-work-as-twitter-tweets-and-get-different-linkif/11153223#11153223)

For that I have used this [LinkEnabledTextView](http://www.orangeapple.org/post/14809024490/android-custom-hyperlinked-textview) and that become easy for me to do the task.

Answer (score 21):

What you can do is create a Custom `ClickableSpan` as below,

```
class MyCustomSpannable extends ClickableSpan
{
    String Url;
    public MyCustomSpannable(String Url) {
        this.Url = Url;
    }
    @Override
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
            // Customize your Text Look if required
        ds.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        ds.setFakeBoldText(true);
        ds.setStrikeThruText(true);
        ds.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
        ds.setUnderlineText(true);
        ds.setShadowLayer(10, 1, 1, Color.WHITE);
        ds.setTextSize(15);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
    }
    public String getUrl() {
        return Url;
    }
}
```

And the use its `onClick()` for opening an Activity or URL. I am adding a demo for loading a URL in `WebView`.

```
String text = "http://www.google.co.in/";
SpannableStringBuilder stringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
MyCustomSpannable customSpannable = new MyCustomSpannable(
                                               "http://www.google.co.in/"){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(customSpannable.getUrl()));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };
        stringBuilder.setSpan(customSpannable, 0, text.length(),
                                         Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

        textView.setText( stringBuilder, BufferType.SPANNABLE );
        textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 12):

Generate your TextView in the following manner:

```
TextView t3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text3);
t3.setText(Html.fromHtml("This is the Simple Text with 
    <a href=\'http://www.google.com\'>Keyword</a> and the 
    <a href='startActivityFromLink://some_info'>Link</a> to browse"));
t3.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Specify your activity the following way:

```
<activity android:name=".TestActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="startActivityFromLink" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I think it should work. Might require some tweaking. I did not get the time to test it. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score -2):

Make Keyword and The link into different TextViews.

Then set the TextView.onClickListener() after you do this.

This is the easiest way, and more logic way.

Comment: yes i know i can do that way...but need to take only one text view