# How to open Google page on click on text view hyperlink in android?

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview

> How to open a Google home page on click on hyperlink text view in android am trying out with following code but on click on the hyperlink it just changing to normal text how to resolve it

Here is the code:

MainActivity.java (in onCreate() )

```
instruction = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.example);

    instruction.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            instruction.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.Google_Instructions)));
            Linkify.addLinks(instruction, Linkify.ALL);
            instruction.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());                
        }
    });
```

strings.xml

```
<string name="Google_Instructions">opens <a href="https://www.google.co.in">Google</a> page </string>
```

layout_test.xml

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/example"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="@string/Google_Instructions"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Comment: Do you want it to open in a browser?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570239/android-linkify-text-spannable-text-in-single-text-view-as-like-twitter-twee. search on so you will many similar posts

Comment: Are you trying to embed a web browser in your app or launch the default browser on your device. The code required for each obviously varies greatly

Comment: @MikeBaglioJr. i want to launch a default browser in the device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i got solution by using adding this small piece of code in java class and also little changes in layout xml file

```
instruction = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.example);

    instruction.setText(Html
            .fromHtml("<b> To open google console </b> "
                    + "<a href=\"https://code.google.com/apis/console\">Click here</a> "));
    instruction.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

layout_test.xml

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/example"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```