# Feedback when click on Links inside a textview

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview

I want a feedback when click on links like google+:

[image]

Im using Linkify right now.
How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this you need the spannable textview in order to handle the click event on specific part of textview. How you can handle the span is defined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570239/android-linkify-text-spannable-text-in-single-text-view-as-like-twitter-twee) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10697453/1078003)
  answer.

Answer (score 0):

I develop a solution to this problem.

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/fredericojssilva/TextViewWithLinks)