# How to make clickable links that starts with http or www in TextView

Tags: java, android, regex, textview

I'm already using `android:autoLink` to make links clickable in `TextView`, but the problem is that i need to check if the link starts with `http` or `www` because if the text is, for example, "some sentence.Error happens" it set the text as clickable and I want to avoid that. Any thought?

---------------- Here is the solution: ----------------

```
private void setUrlClickable(TextView textViewContent, Spanned text) {
        SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(text);
        final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(http|www)\\S*").matcher(spannableString);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources().getColor(R.color.list_section)), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), 0);
            spannableString.setSpan(new TextClickable(matcher.group(0)), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
        textViewContent.setText(spannableString);
        textViewContent.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }
```

Comment: You can override Spannable like shown here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570239/android-linkify-text-spannable-text-in-single-text-view-as-like-twitter-twee

Comment: this code is almost what i need, but this code change the whole text and set the Click listener to the whole text, I need to change just where the link is...  the rest of the text can't have a click listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your text look like this "this link www.yoursite.com is clickable" and you only want the "www.yoursite.com" part clickable you can do like this:

```
private void setText(String text){
    String regexPattern = "(http|www)\\S*";
    final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regexPattern).matcher(text);
    SpannableStringBuilder strBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
    while(matcher.find()){

        ClickableSpan clickable = new ClickableSpan() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Do something with span.getURL() to handle the link click...
            }
        };

        strBuilder.setSpan(clickable, matcher.start(), matcher.end(), 0);

    }
}
```

hope that work for you.

Comment: Thanks, this answer really helped me. I change it a little bit, and I nedded to add this like as well textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **Regular Expression**s to validate the texts you want. For example you can use the following regex for to check if the string is http, ftp , ... link

```
String regex = "^(https?|ftp)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]";
```

And then create a checkText method to enable authoLink :

```
private static boolean checkText(String s, String regex) {
    try {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        return matcher.matches();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: But then i need to change the text color and set the click only in the link, not the whole text... the problem is not recognize the link but how to change the TextView.