# How to handle link click events in a textView

Tags: android, textview, linkmovementmethod

I am using Jsoup to parse the a website, formatting it with `Html.fromHtml()`and displaying the formatted text in a textview.

Also, I'm using `LinkMoveMentmethod.getInstance` to make the links in the textview clickable.

When the links are clicked they fired up a chooser to choose browsers.

Please, how can I override this default behaviour.

For example,  I would want to pass the clicked url to my own activity and use Jsoup to parse it also.

---

### CODE

```
TextView pageContent;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_page_details);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        pageContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dpage_content);
}
....

private void parseHtml(String response) {
        Log.d(TAG, "parsinghtml");
        Document document = Jsoup.parse(response);
        page_content = document.select("div.page-content").first().html();

        Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(page_content, new UILImageGetter(pageContent, this), null );
    }
```

Comment: can't you post that code? it will be easy to help you.

Comment: You can check my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11115929/726863)

Comment: @DevendraSingh, I have added the code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create your custom class which extends LinkMovementMethod.

```
public class LinkClickHandler extends LinkMovementMethod{
    private static LinkClickHandler sInstance;

    public static LinkClickHandler getInstance() {
        if (sInstance == null)
            sInstance = new LinkClickHandler();
        return sInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(TextView widget, 
            Spannable buffer, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
             //Implement your code for handling the click.
        }
         return super.onTouchEvent(widget, buffer, event);
    }
}
```

To use this, change `LinkMovementMethod.getInstance` to `LinkClickHandler.getInstance`

Comment: Thanks. It's showing in logcat that a link was clicked, but how do I start an activity?

Comment: I saw noticed that the your method is fired where the clicked text is a link or just ordinary text.

Answer (score -1):

You can use clickable span

```
     ClickableSpan cs = new ClickableSpan() {  
   @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {  
      Log.d("main", "textview clicked");
        Toast.makeText(Main.this, "textview clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
      } };
     // set the "test " spannable.
     span.setSpan(cs, 0, 5, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
tv.setText(span);
  tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Android Studio could not resolve `span`. And please not that my textview is already formated this way:

`Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(post_content, new UILImageGetter(mytv, this), null );
        mytv.setText(spanned);`

Comment: use following line to create scannable string Spannable span = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable("Your Text");

Comment: Thank you Sir, but like I wrote my textview already has this : `Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(post_content, new UILImageGetter(mytv, this), null ); mytv.setText(spanned);` so, can you please advice how I can make your answer compatible with that?

Comment: create a spannable object from text which you want to make clickable, please share your code, so that I can help you

Comment: plz check without html.fromHtml() method, directly create scannable from post_content, whether is it working ?

Comment: It's working of course but without the ` html.fromHtml() method` the text is raw html.